# SCTV: is "Monster Chiller Horror Theatre" based on "Monsters we Know and Love?"

Tags: sctv

Back in the mid-seventies in Toronto, there was a regular horror movie on CityTV on Saturday nights called "Monsters we Know and Love," which was hosted by Gene Taylor but also featured a sidekick named Igor (played by Art Nefsky). The hosting was pretty hokey (exhibit A:

), but the movies were actually pretty good (I remember "Son of Frankenstein," and I think, "The Blob."

Is there any evidence that this was the basis for the SCTV horror movie show "Monster Chiller Horror Theatre?" The timing and location in Toronto in the mid-seventies suggests so, but are there any interviews or articles which provide a definitive answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Joe Flaherty**, the ***SCTV*** actor portraying **Count Floyd**, has stated that ***Monster Chiller Horror Theater*** is based on a Saturday night program he watched as a child in Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania, called ***Chiller Theater***.

The show, an 11:30PM staple from 1964 until 1983, was hosted by **Bill "Chilly Billy" Cardille** and featured two horror and/or science fiction films of varying scariness and schlockiness quotients. Cardille would introduce the films as himself, then reappear later in pre- and post-commercial segments playing different "scary" characters.

According to Flaherty:

> “Whenever I did ***Monster Chiller Horror Theater***, I tried to get a
>   Pittsburgh reference in there ... The movies he showed were not scary.
>   You had to really suffer through those things, they were so bad. There
>   would be long periods of boredom, and then Chilly Billy would come
>   back on, and that was entertaining.” [Pittsburgh Post-Gazzette](http://www.post-gazette.com/ae/tv-radio/2016/07/01/Longtime-fans-send-their-love-to-ailing-Chilly-Billy-Cardille/stories/201606290206)